# How does the Chinese Politburo maintain a tight grip on the decision-making processes in all of China's government bodies?

Tags: china

How does the Chinese Politburo maintain a tight grip on the decision-making processes in all of China's government bodies such as the National People's Congress and the State Council?

China is known for its highly centralized political system, where the Communist Party is the dominant political force and controls all major decision-making processes within China. The Politburo is the highest decision-making body within the Party, and its members are appointed by the Party's top leadership. My question is how the Politburo maintain a tight grip on the decision-making processes in all of China's government bodies such as the National People's Congress and the State Council so that the ultimate power rests within the control of the top leadership of the Party?

Comment: I believe they can terminate any membership in CCP with corresponding removal from all roles requiring it.